# CSSTidy, HTMLTidy, JSlint pre-commit hooks(Hg) - automation tools

Tags: jslint, htmltidy, pre-commit-hook, csstidy

I am looking for a way to test/validate my `html`, `css`, `js` before they are committed to a repository.

Is there any way to automate this process. Ideally, I would like to have the ability to exclude certain files (js libraries for example).

Answer (score 1):

I've written [jslint4java](http://code.google.com/p/jslint4java), which wraps Doug Crockford's JSLint in a way which makes it simply to invoke from a command line or ant build.  That should be fairly easy to plug into a pre-commit hook.  Have a look at this example of a [JSLint pre-commit hook](http://github.com/jrburke/dvcs_jslint).  Excluding files should be a fairly small addition.

I'm less sure about CSS and HTML validation.  You can download the [W3C CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/DOWNLOAD.html), and again set up a pre-commit hook to call that on CSS files.  The [W3C HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/) is slightly harder to get running as it relies on nsgmls being installed (part of [OpenJade](http://openjade.sourceforge.net/), I think).  You may have better luck with the HTML5 validator.  You may have better luck with the [HTML5 validator](http://html5.validator.nu/).